# UserWarning: The figure layout has changed to tight self._figure.tight_layout(*args, **kwargs)

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

Why do I keep getting this warning whenever I try to use FacetGrid from seaborn?
`UserWarning: The figure layout has changed to tight.`
`self._figure.tight_layout(*args, **kwargs)`
I understand it's a warning and not an error and I also understand it is changing the layout to tight. My question is why does it appear in the first place? Am I missing something?

Example code:

```py
import seaborn as sns

penguins = sns.load_dataset("penguins")
g = sns.FacetGrid(penguins, col="island")
g.map_dataframe(sns.histplot, x="bill_length_mm")
```

This code throws that warning.
What am I doing wrong?
I know I can hide them with warnings module but I don't wanna do that.

Comment: You should be using `sns.displot(kind='hist', ...)` not `sns.FacetGrid`, as per: _Warning - When using seaborn functions that infer semantic mappings from a dataset, care must be taken to synchronize those mappings across facets (e.g., by defining the hue mapping with a palette dict or setting the data type of the variables to category). In most cases, it will be better to use a figure-level function (e.g. relplot() or catplot()) than to use FacetGrid directly._

Comment: Also, the warning is **not reproducible**. [code and plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jAl9a.png). Try updating pandas, matplotlib, and seaborn. If you're using anaconda, then use `conda update --all` at the (base) conda prompt or with the appropriate environment activated.

Comment: This is a matplotlib bug (though it is just an unnecessary warning, not an actual problem): https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/26290

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney I am using standalone Jupyter, not with Anaconda. You can reproduce it with Jupyter 7.0.2. Also, all my packages are updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, this is a [matplotlib bug](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/26290). It was fixed in version 3.7.3, so you can avoid it by upgrading Matplotlib.

One of the [comments](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/26290#issuecomment-1685364394) suggests calling `plt.figure(..., layout='constrained')`, instead of `tight_layout()`, and that matches a few comments I found in the docs, like the [Constrained Layout Guide](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/users/explain/axes/constrainedlayout_guide.html):

> Constrained layout is similar to Tight layout, but is substantially more flexible.

I saw this warning, because I was calling `subplots()`, then repeatedly plotting, calling `tight_layout()`, saving the figure, and calling `cla()`.

I fixed it by removing the call to `tight_layout()` from the loop, and calling `subplots(..., layout='tight')`.

---

Mind that you may need Python 3.11 for matplotlib 3.7.3, as a test with Python 3.10 shows:

```bash
conda install matplotlib[version='>=3.7.3']
```

Output:

```bash
Retrieving notices: ...working... done
Channels:
 - defaults
Platform: linux-64
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: \ warning  libmamba Added empty dependency for problem type SOLVER_RULE_UPDATE
failed

LibMambaUnsatisfiableError: Encountered problems while solving:
  - package matplotlib-3.8.0-py311h06a4308_0 requires matplotlib-base >=3.8.0,<3.8.1.0a0, but none of the providers can be installed

Could not solve for environment specs
The following packages are incompatible
├─ matplotlib-base 3.7.2.*  is installable with the potential options
│  ├─ matplotlib-base 3.7.2, which can be installed;
│  ├─ matplotlib-base [3.7.2|3.8.0] would require
│  │  └─ python >=3.10,<3.11.0a0 , which can be installed;
│  ├─ matplotlib-base 3.7.2 would require
│  │  └─ python >=3.8,<3.9.0a0 , which can be installed;
│  └─ matplotlib-base [3.7.2|3.8.0] would require
│     └─ python >=3.9,<3.10.0a0 , which can be installed;
├─ matplotlib >=3.7.3  is installable with the potential options
│  ├─ matplotlib 3.8.0 would require
│  │  └─ matplotlib-base >=3.8.0,<3.8.1.0a0  with the potential options
│  │     ├─ matplotlib-base [3.7.2|3.8.0], which can be installed (as previously explained);
│  │     ├─ matplotlib-base [3.7.2|3.8.0], which can be installed (as previously explained);
│  │     ├─ matplotlib-base 3.8.0 conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  │     └─ matplotlib-base 3.8.0 would require
│  │        └─ python >=3.12,<3.13.0a0 , which can be installed;
│  ├─ matplotlib 3.8.0 would require
│  │  └─ python >=3.10,<3.11.0a0 , which can be installed;
│  ├─ matplotlib 3.8.0 would require
│  │  └─ python >=3.12,<3.13.0a0 , which can be installed;
│  └─ matplotlib 3.8.0 would require
│     └─ python >=3.9,<3.10.0a0 , which can be installed;
└─ pin-1 is not installable because it requires
   └─ python 3.11.* , which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported.

Pins seem to be involved in the conflict. Currently pinned specs:
 - python 3.11.* (labeled as 'pin-1')
```

Comment: When installing for python 3.10, `!conda install matplotlib[version='>=3.7.3']` throws an error after a while:
`Pins seem to be involved in the conflict. Currently pinned specs:
 - python 3.11.* (labeled as 'pin-1')`. The installation output for >3.7.3 shows that you need python 3.11 to install matplotlib 3.8.0.

Answer (score 0):

Simply update seaborn:

```
pip install seaborn --upgrade
```

Comment: upgrading won't solve this issue. as mentioned by the creator of Seaborn himself, this was a matplotlib bug. idk whether this has been resolved now